# failed to Establishing an encrypted directory connection failed (done - 0.0.2.0:3)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, directory

```
1/25/2017 19:14:38 PM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
1/25/2017 19:16:12 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
1/25/2017 19:16:12 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
1/25/2017 19:16:12 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
1/25/2017 19:16:12 PM.800 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
1/25/2017 19:16:18 PM.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
1/25/2017 19:16:18 PM.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
1/25/2017 19:16:40 PM.000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.12:4304 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
1/25/2017 19:17:08 PM.500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.11:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
1/25/2017 19:17:23 PM.900 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 192.99.11.54:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
1/25/2017 19:18:25 PM.100 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
1/25/2017 19:18:25 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
1/25/2017 19:18:25 PM.100 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
1/25/2017 19:18:35 PM.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
1/25/2017 19:18:35 PM.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
1/25/2017 19:18:35 PM.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
1/25/2017 19:18:35 PM.700 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
1/25/2017 19:18:37 PM.600 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
1/25/2017 19:18:37 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
1/25/2017 19:18:37 PM.600 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
1/25/2017 19:18:37 PM.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host 64186650FFE4469EBBE52B644AE543864D32F43C at 89.187.142.208:443) 
1/25/2017 19:18:37 PM.600 [WARN] 13 connections have failed: 
1/25/2017 19:18:37 PM.600 [WARN]  10 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
1/25/2017 19:18:37 PM.600 [WARN]  3 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a SSL/TLS attack/intrusion. Try using meek pluggable transport, it is designed specially for the cases like this one